# Convert symbol to "unmangled" string

Tags: clojure

I'm making a math game. To store math questions, I'm using the following record:

```
(defrecord Question [args operator]
  Object
  (toString [self]
    (apply str (drop-last 2 (interleave args (repeat \space) (repeat operator) (repeat \space))))))
```

The `toString` "method" converts the args and operator into a infix-operator string.

My problem is, when I attempt to convert a function (like `*`) to a string, I get a qualified, Java-compliant symbol name:

```
(str *)
"clojure.core$_STAR_@a2a3e7"
```

All I want though is to literally convert the symbol to a string, so the `*` function yields `"*"`. The best I've been able to do is use a pre-defined mapping from function-symbol to string; but ideally I'd like to not need the map and just generate the string version of the symbol directly.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're confusing the *symbol* that you can get by evaluating `'*` with the *function* that you can get by evaluating `*`:

```
'*
;;=> *

*
;;=> #function[clojure.core/*]
```

Of course, `'*` isn't the only way to get the symbol `*`. Instead of using the `'` reader macro, you could use the equivalent [`quote`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/quote) special form, or you could use the [`symbol`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/symbol) function to create a symbol from a string, or you could do something else:

```
(quote *)
;;=> *

(symbol "*")
;;=> *
```

If you convert a *symbol* to a string, you get back a string consisting of the name (and, if present, the namespace) of that symbol . If you convert a *function* to a string, you get back the default Java string representation of an object: the name of its class, followed by the `@` character and a hexadecimal representation of its location in memory:

```
(str '*)
;;=> "*"

(str *)
;;=> "clojure.core$_STAR_@a2a3e7"
```

So if you create a `Question` with the *function* `*` as its `operator` and then try to convert that *function* to a string, you'll get this:

```
(str (->Question [4 2] *))
;;=> "4 clojure.core$_STAR_@a2a3e7 2 "
```

On the other hand, if you create a `Question` with the *symbol* `*` as its `operator`, you'll get this instead:

```
(str (->Question [4 2] '*))
;;=> "4 * 2 "
```

Given a symbol, you can resolve it to a var using [`resolve`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/resolve), then get that var's value using [`deref`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/deref):

```
@(resolve '*)
;;=> #function[clojure.core/*]
```

You can't generally go the other way (from a function to a symbol), though. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11911027/5044950) for more details.

Answer (score -1):

Fortunately / unfortunately I realized the answer right after posting this: macros.

```
(defmacro sym->string [sym]
  (str sym))

(sym->string *)
"*"
```

Sorry, I guess I'm not quite awake yet.

---

This is actually wrong: see the comment below.

Comment: This is actually wrong beyond this simple example above. In the code snippet in my question, inside `toString`, I'd like to wrap `operator` in a function that returns the string representation of the operator. Unfortunately, `sym->string` above will literally return `"operator"`, which is obviously not what I want. It won't let me delete this answer though, but it is wrong.