# working with non-namespaced symbols in clojure

Tags: clojure, macros

Here's a working minimal example showing how Clojure can handle non-namespaced symbols:

```clj
(defmacro simple-macro [s]
  (name `~s))

(str "And the answer is "
     (simple-macro v1))
```

Now I'd like to do something more complicated.  Inspired by this example:

```clj
(defn typical-closure []
  (let [names (atom [])]
    (fn [arg] (swap! names conj arg) @names)))

(def Q (typical-closure))
(Q 1)
(Q 2)
;; [1 2]
```

I now want to define a similar closure to take the names of undefined variables.

```clj
(defn take-names-fun []
  (let [names (atom [])]
    #((swap! names conj (simple-macro %)) (deref names))))

(def P (take-names-fun))
(P v1)
```

But this doesn't work as hoped; I get the error:

> Unable to resolve symbol: v1 in this context

Is there a way to fix this so that we can add the name "v1" to the list of names defined above?

I tried using a macro instead (inspired by a syntax trick on page 21 of "Mastering Clojure Macros")... but [this answer](https://ask.clojure.org/index.php/9339/using-atoms-inside-macro) on ask.clojure.org says it doesn't make sense to define a closure over an atom in a macro.

```clj
(defmacro take-names-macro []
  (let [names (atom [])]
    `(fn [~'x] (swap! ~names conj (simple-macro ~'x)) (deref ~names))))

(def R (take-names-macro))
```

And indeed, I get another error here:

> Can't embed object in code, maybe print-dup not defined:

However, there is no such restriction for using atoms inside `defn`.   Maybe at the end of the day I need to put my symbols in a namespace...?

Comment: Besides the answers below, you may find this question helpful since it shows that for some purposes your macro must call `eval`:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71803261/clojure-macros-call-function-from-macro/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite sure what it is that you're ultimately trying to accomplish.

But, since `P` is a function, it will **always** evaluate its arguments.  So, if you pass it an undefined symbol, you'll get the error you got.  Instead, you have to create a macro so that you can quote the undefined symbol (to stop the evaluation of the argument) and then pass that to `P`.  Here is an example that does that.

```clj
user> (defn take-names-fun []
        (let [names (atom [])]
          (fn [arg] (swap! names conj (name  arg)))))
#'user/take-names-fun
user> (def P (take-names-fun))
#'user/P
user> (defmacro PM [s] `(P (quote ~s)))
#'user/PM
user> (PM v1)
["v1"]
user> (PM v2)
["v1" "v2"]
user>
```

You might find the article on [Evaluation in Clojure](https://clojure.org/reference/evaluation) helpful.

Comment: There is no need to use `(deref names)` at the end of function- `(swap! names conj (name arg))` returns updated value of atom.

Answer (score 1):

@dorab's answer is nice.
But you could also tell yourself: "When entering undefined variables into a function, I have to quote them to avoid evaluation of them!"

So, after:

```
(defn typical-closure []
  (let [names (atom [])]
    (fn [arg] (swap! names conj arg) @names)))

(def Q (typical-closure))
```

Do:

```
user=> (Q 'v1)
[v1]
user=> (Q 'v2)
[v1 v2]
user=> (Q 3)
[v1 v2 3]
user=> (Q 'v4)
[v1 v2 3 v4]
user=>
```

In this way you don't need the macro and you can alternate between evaluated and not-evaluated arguments (undefined symbols).

Comment: Thanks, that's an illustrative "reveal" of the magic trick.

Comment: Welcome @JoeCorneli - this is the magic of lisp - or the magic of `quote`. Because you have fine-grained control over when something gets evaluated. A macro doesn't evaluate its arguments at the beginning before entering the macro body - but there is an implicit evaluation step at the very end of the macro. This delay in evaluation gives you the possibility to manipulate the code before evaulation. Functions evaluate each of their arguments before entering the function body. But by giving quoted arguments into function - you have the symbols as arguments.

Comment: But in that situation the difference to macros is that functions don't have the late evaluation step at the end. Therefore such functions can only return the manipulated symbols without the final evaluation. But sometimes you want this even - in functions used to manipulate code in macros. So you can mix up functions and macros wildly in the macro body.

Answer (score 0):

So with the way `fn`'s are written in clojure there is unfortunately no way to get the name of the var being passed as a param from within the `fn` body.. Someone with more experience with the clojure src may be able to explain better why that is, my initial guess would be that it has something to do with keeping thread local scopes isolated and lazy.

But there's absolutely nothing stopping you from writing a macro that wraps other macros using your closure idea!

Here's an example of how something like that may be written:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/11857444